# How can I modify this function to delete all the strikethrough text in my excel file?

Tags: python, excel, formatting, xlwings

I found a bit of code on another question of this forum, that is supposed to remove strikethrough text in an excel file, however when I tried to use a version corresponding to what I want it to do, it removes the text that is strikethrough in some cells with mixed fonts, all the cells that are completely strikethrough, but does not remove the strikethrough text in some of the cells with mixed fonts.

As stated above I tried a function found on this forum, changed to the use I want of it:

```
def process_eCRF_file(file_path, outdir):
    if "eCRF" not in file_path:
        return

    wb = xw.Book(file_path)
    for ws in wb.sheets:
        for cell in ws.used_range:
            cell_coord = str(cell.address.replace('$', ''))
            print('Cell: ' + cell_coord + ', Cell value: ' + str(cell.value), end=', ')

            # check if cell is merged
            if cell.merge_cells:
                merge_area = cell.merge_area
                has_strikethrough = False
                for merge_cell in merge_area:
                    merge_cell_st = merge_cell.font.impl.xl.Strikethrough
                    if merge_cell_st:
                        has_strikethrough = True
                        ws.range(merge_area.address).api.UnMerge()
                        break
                if has_strikethrough:
                    continue

            # check for strikethrough formatting in current cell
            st = cell.font.impl.xl.Strikethrough
            print('ST value: ' + str(st), end=' ')
            if st:
                print(', Cell has strikethrough font.')
                cell.clear()
            elif st is None:
                print(', Cell has mixed font.')
                num_chars = len(cell.value)
                print(cell_coord + ' Text length: ' + str(num_chars) + ' characters.')
                print("Individual character font strikethrough?")
                char_position = 0
                while char_position < num_chars:
                    cur_text_value = cell.characters[char_position].text
                    print("'" + cur_text_value + "'", end=' ')
                    char_is_st_font = cell.characters[char_position].font.impl.xl.Strikethrough
                    print(char_is_st_font)

                    if char_is_st_font:
                        cell.characters[char_position].api.Delete()
                        num_chars -= 1  # decrease the text length by 1
                    else:
                        char_position += 1
            else:
                print(', Cell has NO strikethrough font.')

    wb.save(os.path.join(outdir, 'processed_' + os.path.basename(file_path)))
    wb.close()
```

However when I use it, I get this:

Input
[Excel tab input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrdbK.png)

Output
[Excel tab output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YJby.png)

What can be changed so that the rest of the strikethrough text is removed too?

Comment: Yes I recognise the code. I ran your example code on a duplication of your example sheet and all text blocks with strikethrough font were removed for me. I dont see the text blocks that you show as not being removed are any different from the others that would cause an issue. Of course I can only duplicate the sheet visually so if there is some difference in the cells with remaining strikethrough text blocks that would prevent it being removed I cannot determine visually what that might be.

Comment: The code has extensive printout; including for each cell determined as containing strikethrough, each character returns a True/False state as to whether it is strikethrough so you can debug what happens with those cells. From your screenshot, the first cell with strikethrough remaining is C9, the printout for this is; **Cell: C9, Cell value: O srhesrhsrehhn O rththrdhdtrhdt O olrshhtrsjkttrkrktrk O erhsjgklkyltytdltl O sgereezkokmo, `ST value: None , Cell has mixed font.`** which means there is some text with strikethrough in the cell, it then determines that text to be `olrshhtrsjkttrkrktrk`

Comment: Would it be possible that if a cell has the strikethrough format, but no characters in it the program gets stuck and does not process it correctly? For me the program gets stuck on the first character that is strikethrough in C9, it keeps on printing "o" True, then after a few seconds switch to the next cell and does the same thing, gets stuck on the first character but not removing any text.